# Haskell Integers; What exactly is going on here?

Tags: haskell, biginteger

Having recently become curious about Haskell, I've started doing some reading.  `Integer`s are blowing my mind.

When we say that an `Integer` can be arbitrarily large, does that mean what I think it means (i.e. the size of an `Integer` is not restricted by the address width of the OS)?

Say I had enough RAM available to hold a number with a billion place values.  Would Haskell be able to work with that number?

Can anybody describe to me what's going on under the hood to make this possible?

Comment: **Hint:** Is the arithmetic that you do on a piece of paper arbitrarily limited to some number of digits?

Comment: Try it in ghci: `10^(10^6)` has a million place values. It ain't a billion, but what's a factor of `10^(10^9-10^6)` between friends?

Comment: Gahh my brain! I mean... technically I'm restricted by the quantity of graphite or ink at my disposal and the total surface area of the medium that receives aforementioned ink/graphite.  But given a sufficiently large sheet of paper and quantity of ink/graphite, no.

Comment: @HandsomeGorilla The numbers you can work with using `Integer` are similarly limited by the total amount of RAM you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell's `Integer` type is colloquially known as a [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) type.  It works in much the same way as you might perform math calculations by hand: by dealing with numeric digits instead of fixed-precision binary words.

Bignum libraries typically store numbers as a *collection of digits.*  Arithmetic works the same way as if you had performed it by hand; by manipulating the digits.

Comment: Ah okay.  This gives me a more intuitive notion of how it works.  Could I think about an `Integer` as a list of character digits, where position indicates place value? Is that an over-simplification?

Comment: Yes, with the caveat that a digit isn't necessarily a decimal digit (base ten).  Bigint libraries can, and often do, use some other base like 256 (byte digits) or 65536 (sixteen bit word digits).

Comment: Good Bignum libraries store numbers as a collection of machine words instead of digits. That makes life a lot easier, and makes calcualtions a lot faster. The latter is important because BigNums are generally not hardware supported and therefore a lot slower than machine supported ones. Many languages will use machine words/integers as much as possible, and only resort to BigNums if the results get too large for one machine word.

Answer (score 5):

> Say I had enough RAM available to hold a number with a billion place values. Would Haskell be able to work with that number?

```
Prelude> length . show $ 10^1000000000
1000000001
```

Granted, it did take quite a lot of memory

[image]

But if you think about it – one byte can actually store numbers up to 256>100, i.e. you can store more than two decimal digits in each byte. A number with a billion digits should therefore take less than 500 MB to store... well, evidently there is some overhead here with the multiplications needed (also when I `show` the number I'm generating an inefficient list-string) but nothing dramatic.

BTW, it's not Haskell/GHC which does these computations but [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), which is used by GHC.

But you *could* easily implement such a type yourself in Haskell. E.g. for simplicity, with a list of decimal digits as you suggested<sup>†</sup>

```
newtype DecDigit = DD { getDecDig :: Int }

instance Num [DecDigit] where
  fromInteger n | n < 10     = [DD $ fromInteger n]
                | otherwise  = let (cs,ls) = n`divMod`10
                               in DD $ fromInteger ls : fromInteger cs
  n + [] = n
  [] + n = n
  (DD n₀ : n) + (DD m₀ : m)
     | s₀<10      = DD s₀ : n+m
     | otherwise  = DD (s₀-10) : n+m+[DD 1]
   where s₀ = n₀+m₀

  ...
```

Multiplication is a tad more difficult, but basically, as said by Robert Harvey, it's all like you'd calculate with pen and paper.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>This is very inefficient! Actual implementation would use not decimal digits, but fully exploit machine-size words (probably using 128-bit or even 256-bit primitive operation of modern processors).</sub>